# Scope and Claims parameters are not forwarded to another OIDC provider from Keycloak server

Tags: openid, openid-connect, keycloak

Just started to work with Keycloak. I created an Identity Provider, setup everything and when client performs openid request it successfully goes to my provider backend through keycloak. But scope field is fully replaced with ‘Default claims’ in provider settings and doesn’t contain requested claims.
I created a client scope and put it in 'optional list', so it should be sent if requested by client but it doesn’t help. What can be a problem?

Also I have a question about claims parameter, now I found that in realm configuration “claims_parameter_supported”:false. is it possible to configure it?

Answer (score 0):

> What can be a problem?

You need to add your client scope to "Assigned Optional Client Scopes" on "Client Scopes" page of your client. You can check if it works as expected on the page which is shown after clicking "Evaluate" sub tab.

> Also I have a question about claims parameter, now I found that in realm configuration “claims_parameter_supported”:false. is it possible to configure it?

Keycloak has not supported it yet. Please refer to [this ticket](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/KEYCLOAK-3226).

Comment: Thank you for respond @Kohei, I've already put scope to "Assigned Optional Client Scopes" on "Client Scopes" page and after evaluation it is shown in the table correctly. But it still doesn't forwarded to another OIDC provider. 

an example of the url that I use to request claims : `http://localhost:8000/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/auth?client_id=ed07b0fc-85d9-487c-b553-d75eea1e80d3&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%3A4201%2Fprofile&response_type=code&scope=openid%20email`

but _email_  is not forwarded

Comment: Umm, please go to `Client Scopes > email > Mappers > email ` and check if three `Add to ***` settings are `ON` as you expected.